# Entitiy Framework 6 Add-Migration throwing System.ArgumentNullException on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

Running Entity Framework 6 `Add-Migration` on Visual Studio 2022 produces error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type`. It worked with Visual Studio 2019 fine.

Running `Add-Migration` should produce migrations, without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2022 supports the latest version of Entity Framework 6.4.4, not earlier versions, there are two possible solutions:

1. Update Entity Framework to 6.4.4
2. Use Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Updating the Entity Framework nuget version to 6.4.4 solved the issue for me!